# Datatable link stops working after page one

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, datatable

I have a datatable with a data-href inside to create a link to a forum page, My issue lies in the place that my datatable link works great on page one, but when I go to page two I can no longer follow the link,but it still has all the data of a link when I inspect element.
My JS and Style for the link within the datatable

```
<style>
        tr.clickable-row { cursor: pointer; }
        tr.clickable-row:hover { background-color:#F0F8FF;}
        </style>
        <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".clickable-row").on('click',$('.clickable-row'),function() {
        window.document.location = $(this).data("href");
    });
});
</script>
```

All rows are called upon by MySQL tables to populate the data and are pulled correctly.

```
echo "<tr class='clickable-row' data-href='viewPage.php?id=".inv_forum_page()."&forum=".$forum['id']."'>
    <td>".$authorname."</td><td>".$posttype."".$forum['subject']."</td><td>".$forum['replies']."</td><td>".$forum['views']."</td>
    </tr>";
```

I don't feel like posting the entire function as it's quite a bit of code when I don't believe it's the issue since it works on page one I believe it has to do with my Jquery, but if you want to look at the function itself it is on github under
https://github.com/Doxramos/Invontrol/blob/master/plugins/inv_forum/functions.php
line 75-123
I read on delegated events and I believe that that's scripted correctly, s I'm not sure what the issue is at this point.

Comment: Tried a vanilla DataTables with nothing customized, just to see if it works?

Comment: Can't test that.  The problem is the custom link within the tr

Comment: In this situation, I recommend you to generate the entire table on DataTables(DT), and serve the data via Ajax... I don't entirely know why, but for me, this way was the only one that worked... Look here to get started: https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use below code

your problem is called `Event Delegation`.

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a
>   parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a
>   selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the
>   future.

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
       $(document).on('click','.clickable-row',function() {
          window.document.location = $(this).data("href");
       });
    });
</script>
```

if you call click event every time new page call use below code.

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
       $(document).off('click').on('click','.clickable-row',function() {
          window.document.location = $(this).data("href");
       });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately no, That actually broke the entire script and it no longer worked on the first page either.

Comment: @MorganGreen where you call this script ? no need to call when second page load . add above code in main page where you create table .

Comment: The second function actually worked. I've never actually used document.off at all, I'm going to have to look into it more because now that I know it works I want to figure out why haha. Thank you very much. And it's only called once within the page.

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/   this link will help you to understand  event delegation. happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

You have given class 'clickable-row' to tr. Instead of tr class name, try jQuery 'on' method on table class name. For example, assing class 'clickable-tbl' to table tag and modify jQuery code as follows:

```
$(".clickable-tbl").on('click',$('.clickable-row'),function() {
        window.document.location = $(this).data("href");
    });
```

Comment: While I appreciate the input. `<style>tr.clickable-row { } </script>` Would apply to the table rows with clickable-row attached as the class. No where in there was there ever a mention of clickable-tbl as that would simply be overworking something. The above answer was actually the one that ended up working. Thank you anyways.

Comment: The above answer will work. But each time, the click event will search 'clickable-row' element in entire dom. If you add a class to table and write 'click' event on that then 'clickable-row' element will be searched inside table and not in entire dom.