# Not getting record from database using ajax call in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am new in laravel development. I am getting record of user registered from database

**HTML code**

```
<meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<table id="user_table" class="table  table-row-bordered gy-5 gs-7">
  <thead>
    <tr class="fw-bold fs-6 text-gray-800">
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Action</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
   @foreach ($register_users as $value)
    <tr>
       <td>{{ $value->id }}</td>
       <td>{{ $value->name.' '.$value->lname }}</td>
       <td>{{ $value->email }}</td>
       <td style="display: inline-flex;">
       <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="{{ $value->id }}"  data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#activateModal" class="viewDetailModal btn btn-warning btn-hover-rise me-5 btn-sm" style="margin: 1px">View Details</a>
       </td>
   </tr>
  @endforeach
 </tbody>
```

When I clicked on view details button then ajax call for get single user data based on user id

**JQUERY code**

```
$(".viewDetailModal").click(function(e) {

     e.preventDefault();

     var customer_id = $(this).data('id');
     var _token = $("input[name='_token']").val();

     $.ajax({
        url: "{{ route('get.user.details') }}",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {_token:_token, customer_id:customer_id},
        success: function (response){
            console.log(response);

            if(response.lname)
              {
                 response.lname = response.lname;
              }
              else
              {
                 response.lname = '';
              }

           $('#user_id').text(response.id);
           $('#user_name').text(response.name+' '+response.lname);
           $('#user_email').text(response.email);
           $('#user_mobile_no').text(response.mobile_no);
           $('#user_cnic_no').text(response.cnic_no);
           $('#user_passport_no').text(response.passport_no);
           $('#user_country_id').text(response.country_id);
           $('#user_city_id').text(response.city_id);        
            
        }
    });
  });
```

I am using datatable for **user table** Now issue is that when I am on second page, second page mean that when we are using datatable then datatable predefined pages number bottom right side, clicked on view details then ajax call is not run for get user record from database even I searched user from search field. Only when I am on first page ajax call is working fine. I also checked console errors may be there is some mistake from me to get single user data when I am on second page but I saw no errors on it.

**Datatable code**

```
$("#user_table").DataTable({
        "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
         "language": {
         "lengthMenu": "Show _MENU_",
         },
         "dom":
         "<'row'" +
         "<'col-sm-6 d-flex d-none d-sm-none d-md-block align-items-center justify-content-md-start'l>" +
         "<'col-12 col-sm-6 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-md-end'f>" +
         ">" +

         "<'table-responsive'tr>" +

         "<'row'" +
         "<'col-sm-12 col-md-5 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center justify-content-md-start'i>" +
         "<'col-sm-12 col-md-7 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center justify-content-md-end'p>" +
         ">"
 });
```

Comment: So what's your question? I only see statements

Comment: please read last paragraph

Comment: I did, but there are no question marks anywhere, just statements. The last paragraph doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Is the click function even called second time?

Comment: My issue is that datatable provide predefined pagination number on bottom right down, When I am on page 1 then click on button get record of single user
when I am on page 2 or other page or even I searched user then click on button, ajax call is not working

Comment: Do the links work for any row if you don't use Datatable?

Comment: Would this solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30542471/datatable-link-stops-working-after-page-one